# Set Different Value on WebGrid Data if One Specific Row and Column is Null

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am working on MVC using WebGrid and WebGridColumns.

I have a list of data on my Model, but some of the columns on my data are null so I want to specify a different value for null columns.

Here is a sample of my code on View:

```
var objData = Model.myListofUsers;
var webMyGrid= new WebGrid();
webMyGrid.Bind(objData);

//Build a list of columns
List<WebGridColumn> webColumns= new List<WebGridColumn>();

webColumns.Add(new WebGridColumn { ColumnName = "strName", Header = "Name"});
    webColumns.Add(new WebGridColumn { ColumnName = "strPhone", Header = "Phone"});
```

Not all Names have Phone numbers so I want to specify if there is no Phone number, I want to declare some words like "User have no phone" instead on those fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Format property of WeGridColumn could help you.

```
   webColumns.Add(new WebGridColumn { ColumnName = "strName", Header = "Name", Format= (item) => String.IsNullOrEmpty(item.strName)? "Your Message": item.strName});
```